# React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

```
const fetchAPIDataCountries = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await 
        axios.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries');
        const { data } = response
        const { countries } = data
        const newData = _.map(countries, item => ({ name: item.name }))
        console.log("fetchCountries -> newData", countries)
        return newData
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAPI = async () => {
   let dataCountries = await fetchAPIDataCountries();
   setCountries(dataCountries)`enter code here`;
  };
  return () => fetchAPI();
 }, []);
```

i didn't get data from api but i try remove `return()` in `useEffect()` just wrote `fetchAPI()`, It 's ok. I don't know what happen here, can anyone explain it.Thank you.

Comment: You're defining a `fetchAPI` function in `useEffect()`, but you don't actually CALL it anywhere. Don't worry about returning the API call, after your define `const FetchAPI = ...` just call it on the next line, `fetchAPI()`.

Comment: The way you wrote it, you told react to call `fetchAPI` on `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the return value which is a function in useEffect is meant to be a cleanup function and is used when you want to run something when the component unmounts or before the useEffect is run next-time

In your case you just with to fetchData inside useEffect, in such a case, you only need to call fetchAPI and not return it

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAPI = async () => {
   let dataCountries = await fetchAPIDataCountries();
   setCountries(dataCountries)`enter code here`;
  };
  fetchAPI();
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return () => fetchAPI()
```

is used as compoentWillUnmount() life cycle method so above code will execute on component unmount .
you have to do as following

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAPI = async () => {
   let dataCountries = await fetchAPIDataCountries();
   setCountries(dataCountries)`enter code here`;
  };
  fetchAPI();
 }, []);
```